# Is it ok to chmod a+w files under sys/platform in a desktop env?

Tags: security, chmod, polkit, keyboard-backlight

I developed and maintain a keyboard backlight CLI/GUI for Linux-running Clevo laptops (https://github.com/webketje/tuxedo-backlight-control). Some of the files this CLI/GUI needs to alter are under `/sys/devices/platform/tuxedo_keyboard/`. At the moment I am using polkit/pkexec to prompt for temporary admin permissions.

However, someone created a fork of my repo and added a commit which activates a Linux service that makes the files under the `/sys/devices/platform/tuxedo_keyboard/` directory writable for all (https://github.com/encarsia/tuxedo-backlight-control/commit/34da8989613c29c0faab67220a4391c460d2aa6a).

Obviously I would love to not have to prompt for the admin password every 5min just to change the keyboard backlight color, but I am wondering **security-wise, is this ok**? If so, how can I make sure after a new tuxedo_keyboard driver install, that the files remain writable?

Comment: I'd at least give the files to a group, and add the real, human users to that group.

Comment: Also remember the /sys files are recreated at boot so it will have to be changed each time the "driver" is loaded.  The way I have seen others deal with this issue is using udev rules to assign write permission.

Comment: In particular, the `plugdev` group is used on Debian and family like in stribika's suggestion